# Little random string generator that unfortunately sometimes fails. Please help me fix it

Tags: ruby, algorithm, random

From some StackOverflow answer I have that neat little function to generate a 10 character String with only a-z and 0-9 chars:
`rand(36**10).to_s(36)`

The problem is that it sometimes fails and only generates 9 characters. But I really like the ease and speed of it. Any suggestions how to fix it so that I can be sure that it always generates exactly 10 characters? (Without any loops or checking.)

Comment: does it really have to be random in the sense that any combination of letters and numbers is equally likely to come up? because this is hardly the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you randomly generate a number less than 36<sup>9</sup>, it ends up being a 9-character string.  Left-pad it with zeros:

```
rand(36**10).to_s(36).rjust(10, "0")
```

Example:

```
irb(main):018:0> (36**9).to_s(36)
=> "1000000000"
irb(main):019:0> (36**9 - 1).to_s(36)
=> "zzzzzzzzz"
irb(main):020:0> (36**5).to_s.rjust(10, "0")
=> "0060466176"
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. The one thing I don't like is that it is just filled up ... not really random at all. Ok, I could fill it up with some random chars, but then I could also generate each char on it's own.

Comment: @Zardos What's wrong with padding zero's? (besides you don't like it).One of every 36 numbers will start with a zero; one of every 36**2 will start with two zero's (or 5's or 'a's)

Comment: @Zardoz: If what you are attempting to achieve a uniform distribution of all letters and numbers in all 10 positions, then your approach is inherently flawed.  If you just want something "kind of" random, keep up this approach.  A better approach toward uniformity would be to generate each character on its own as you suggest.

Comment: I guess you are right. I am now going a complete different way. Generate some base64 string with the help of some OpenSSL library and extract 10 chars (as the base64 strings also contains some "ugly" chars).

Comment: @Zardoz Perhaps if you explained what you're trying to achieve, we can suggest something else. Both approaches sound like horrid kludges.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a random string of characters and numbers but no single character will appear more than once

```
(('a'..'z').to_a + (0..9).to_a).shuffle[1..10].join
```

To "fix" the number of possible outcomes you just do this:

```
a = (('a'..'z').to_a + (0..9).to_a)
a = a * 10
p a.shuffle[1..10].join
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just generate string where every character can be only one time present?! That would shrink the result space a lot.

Comment: yes it would, you will get 10333147966386144929666651337523200000000 combinations as opposed to much less than 3656158440062976 with your original method (unless I'm misscalculating something)

Comment: sorry I was indeed misscalculating, with my method you would get 16654322805120000 combinations

Comment: I've added a new version wich allows multiple occurrences of each letter

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
>> require 'md5'
=> true
>> MD5::hexdigest(Time.now.to_f.to_s)[0..9]
=> "89d83d3516"
```

Comment: isn't that just an hex number? I think the to_s(36) is meant to generate all the lettes from a to z

Comment: not only that, it will generate the same values if called quickly enough

Comment: I am looking for more than just hex strings. It should be possible to use every char in a-z and 0-9.

Comment: @ammon call Time.now.to_f 1000 times in console and you'll never get the same value, thus, hexdigest will never return the same value

Comment: Run this in `irb -f`: `_t = []; 100.times { _t << Time.now.to_f }; puts _t` and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the idea of using `rand(36**5)` by @Mark Rushakoff, this shuffles the zero-padded string to randomize the characters:

```
('%010x' % [rand(36**5)]).chars.to_a.shuffle.join # => "4a04020701"
('%010x' % [rand(36**5)]).chars.to_a.shuffle.join # => "0e092f0a03"
('%010x' % [rand(36**5)]).chars.to_a.shuffle.join # => "03e240e800"
```

To work around Ruby not allowing zero-padded strings in the `format` I have to switch to padding in the method chain, which is basically what Mark did. To avoid strings of leading zeros this breaks it back down to an array and shuffles the string and rejoins it.

```
rand(36**5).to_s(36).rjust(10, '0').chars.to_a.shuffle.join # => "e80000h00b"
rand(36**5).to_s(36).rjust(10, '0').chars.to_a.shuffle.join # => "00bv0dy00p"
rand(36**5).to_s(36).rjust(10, '0').chars.to_a.shuffle.join # => "v0hw000092"
```

Comment: It only generates numbers. The rand of Mark does generate not only numbers but other chars as well (a-z, 0-9).

Comment: I tweaked it to use 0-9a-z. It's a good puzzle to see if I can get base(36) using `format`.

Comment: Perl lets us use zero-padded strings, but it looks like Ruby doesn't. Rats. I suspect that's why @Mark Rushakoff went with `rjust`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..9).to_a).sample(8).join
```

Comment: In 1.9 `[*?a..?z,*?A..?Z,*0..9].sample(8).join` does the same.